# Fixing error - There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first

Tags: c#, .net

In a C# script, I try to read a table with a SqlDataReader object and then drop the table.
Its really that simple.

This is the code I use -

```
SqlConnection conn = getAWorkingDbConnection();//Always gives me a good connection
SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
SqlDataReader dataReader;

sqlCmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
sqlCmd.Connection = conn;

sqlCmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM GlassTable";
dataReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

//Code to read rows with SqlDataReader and print them to a file.

sqlCmd.CommandText = "DROP TABLE GlassTable";
sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();// BAD !!!
```

I get this error - 
System.InvalidOperationException: There is already an open DataReader associated 
with this Command which must be closed first.

I saw the API for the ExecuteReader method, but it does not answer my problem. 
Why does this error happen and how do I fix it ?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't want to use any MARS for this.

Comment: Create a new command with a new connection. But can you explain why not MARS?

Comment: @Steve - Well, actually this code is used in a SSIS C# script. I use a SSIS (an ETL tool) database connection manager which I suspect cannot allow you to use MARS. You can use mars if you generate the strings yourself. But, probably not if you lift it off a SSIS connection manager.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is that you are not disposing of the objects you are using. For that purpose is better to always use `using` structure, since it will guarantee you that everything is gonna is disposed of. Try the code below:

```
sqlCmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM GlassTable";
using (dataReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    //Code to read rows with SqlDataReader and print them to a file.
}
```

Furthermore, you don't have to use `ExecuteReader` on a query that does not return records.

```
sqlCmd.CommandText = "DROP TABLE GlassTable";
int recordsAffected = sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: oh. yes. its a non query

Comment: The code is not working. I get the same error again.

Comment: @blasto did you make sure you put all `IDataReader`s  in a separate using block, and the `ExecuteNonQuery()` _outside_ these blocks? The reader closes when the `using` block ends.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `using`-statement to dipose all unmanaged resources as soon as possible:

```
using(SqlConnection conn = getAWorkingDbConnection())
using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM GlassTable", conn))
{
    sqlCmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
    conn.Open();
    using (SqlDataReader dataReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (dataReader.Read())
        { 
            // do something useful ...
        }
    }
    sqlCmd.CommandText = "DROP TABLE GlassTable";
    sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Thanks tim. I think there should be a ; after using(SqlConnection conn = getAWorkingDbConnection())

Comment: @blasto: no, the scope of this using includes the next using, similar to a `foreach(var obj in seq)foreach(var otherObj in obj.OtherSeq){}`. I could surround it with `{}`. I prefer this to avoid indent.

Comment: Thanks. Is it okay if i use SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand() inside the second "using" and then initialize sqlCmd inside the "using".

Comment: @blasto: yes, you can even declare it before the `using` if you want. The `using` just ensures that the `IDisposable` gets disposed (which also closes the connection) even on error.

Comment: just to be sure i am saying it correctly - SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(); using(sqlCmd = getCommandFromSomewhere()){//use it here}. Is that correct ?

Comment: @blasto: yes, that's no problem. But `new SqlCommand()` is redundant, isn't it? And `getConnFromSomewhere` has a wrong name if it returns a command.

Comment: Yes, I changed the method name.

Comment: tim, i get the same error with your code. I will post the whole code here.

Answer (score 1):

You need to close the data reader.

The quickest way to do this is use a `using` statement to Dispose of the data reader for you:

```
using (var dataReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader())
{
      //Stuff
}
```

Or if you want to keep the same instance, you can call `Close()` in a `try...finally` block.

Comment: Man I'm bad at English tonight, does that read better @Selman22 ?